# is possible to remote desktop two users in one pc simultaneously in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop

I wanted to remote desktop my two user account created in windows 7 simultaneously I have the concurrent patch for windows 7, however my modem router doesn't support remote desktop. is there any software that allows remote desktop simultaneously two users in one computer through the internet? I have tried team viewer and logmein, but it didn't allow two users

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no way to do this.  Windows 7 will only allow one user to be logged on at a time.  At best, you can log in with one user, then switch users in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Client version only supports one session at the same time. Consider to change the Windows 7 to a Windows Server, which will support two active sessions.